# How to take a Probability Proportional to Size (PPS) Unequal Probability sample using R?

Tags: r, probability, statistical-sampling

I have very little programming experience, but I'm working on a statistics project and would like to generate an unequal probability sample where the inclusion probability of a unit is based on its size (PPS).

Basically, I have two datasets:

- `ds1` lists US states and the parameter I'm trying to estimate
- `ds2` has the population size of each state.

My questions:

1. I want to use R to select a random sample from the first dataset using inclusion probabilities based on the population of each state (second dataset).
2. Also is there any way to use R to calculate these Generalized Unequal Probability Estimator formulas?

[image: Generalized Unequal Probability Estimator]
[image: Estimated Variance of Generalized Unequal Probability Estimator]

Also just a note on the formulas: pi_i is inclusion probability and pi_ij is joint inclusion probability.

Comment: Links are ephemeral, it's not ok to reference something in text in a linked image. State what it is: *"link to formulas for Generalized Unequal Probability Estimator"* Anyway what is `y` supposed to: the independent variable, the population or what?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't know. I edited it to get rid of the link. Also y is the variable of interest. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Your second question should be asked as a separate question, and is offtopic on SO, or at least won't get a great response - best to ask statistical questions at sister site [CrossValidated](https://statistics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's called ***weighted sampling***. Simply set the weight to the size of the state, strictly you don't even need to normalize them by `1/sum(sizes)` although it's always good practice to. There are tons of duplicate posts on SO showing how to do weighted sampling.

The only tiny complication is that you need to do a `join()` of the datasets `ds1, ds2`. Show us what code you've tried if it's causing problems. Recommend you use either `dplyr` or `data.table`.

Your second question should be asked as a separate question, and is offtopic on SO, or at least won't get a great response - best to ask statistical questions at sister site [CrossValidated](http://statistics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for the same in R - [pps](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pps/index.html) and the documentation is [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pps/pps.pdf).

Also, there is another package called survey with a bit of [documentation here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-do-i-analyze-survey-data-with-a-probability-proportional-to-size-sampling-design/).

I'm not sure of the difference between the two and haven't used them myself. Hope this is what you're looking for.